# Is there a way to implement a Neural Network able to work with vector target?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a Neural network model using keras, where the output is a vector of five elements. 
Basically the target contains elements from 0 to 4 and nan. So I can have some targets like
[0,3,2,1,4] and others like [nan, 0, nan, 1 ,2]. The important thing is that the element in the vector are not repeated, only nan can.

One solution I tried was to use something like one hot encoder for the target, in this way I transformed a target in a 25 components vector, with all zeros and 1 in corrispondence of the number to map ( i.e. [nan, 0, nan, 1 ,2] -> [(0 , 0 ,0 ,0 ,0),(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0,0)] - i'm using the round brackets only to highlight groups of five element).

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood, what you're trying to predict is a list of 5 elements, each of them takes a discrete value from the {nan, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

What you'll need to do is training 5 neural networks (for each position of the list), each one predicts a value from the previous set, thus, you need to hot-encode the outputs, apply a softmax and select the highest probability for each of neural network.

when trying to predict the output list of a new sample, what you're going to do is predict every position, put them in the list and Voila !

```
def predict_sample(sample):
    pos_0 = nn0.predict(sample)[0]
    pos_1 = nn1.predict(sample)[0]
    pos_2 = nn2.predict(sample)[0]
    pos_3 = nn3.predict(sample)[0]
    pos_4 = nn4.predict(sample)[0]
    outp = [pos_0, pos_1, pos_2, pos_3, pos_4]
    # if nan is encoded as 5 then:
    outp[outp == 5] = np.nan
    return outp
```

You cannot assume NaNs will be unique at prediction, only the data will affect that but what you can do if for example taking the second highest probability when already a NaN is predicted at a certain position of the list.

Comment: I already tried something like that, the problem is that also if the singles neural network have good performances when I put togheter the predictions, it does not perform well, because if just one neural network gives the wrong output  the whole target is not reached. Also, keep in mind that there is some correlation between the elments of my vector target, so I was looking for an approach that  does not separate the nets